# An R beginner's simple question of Loop: access elements in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

I have some code that works to scrape one webpage. But I need to scrape 500 web pages. When I adapted and set it up by using the loop function, it didn't work. Could someone point out where I was wrong? Really appreciate it!

**Original code that works for one webpage (someone else wrote)**

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
a <- c("https://fortune.com/company/walmart/")

  json_data <- read_html(a) |>
    html_element("script#preload") |> 
    html_text() |>
    sub("\\s*window\\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ", "", x = _, perl = TRUE) |>
    sub(";\\s*$", "", x = _, perl = TRUE) |>
    fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE)
  
  
  
  temp<-gsub(".*https://fortune.com","",(a))
  page_data <- json_data$components$page[[temp]]
  
  find_by_name <- function(list_data, name, elem = NULL) {
    idx <- which(sapply(list_data, \(x) x$name) == name, arr.ind = TRUE)
    stopifnot(length(idx) > 0)
    if (length(idx) > 1) { idx <- idx[1] }
    dat <- list_data[[idx]]
    if (is.null(elem)) dat else dat[[elem]]
  }
  
  info_data <- page_data |> 
    find_by_name("body", "children") |>
    find_by_name("company-about-wrapper", "children") |>
    find_by_name("company-information", "config")
  
  
  info_data$employees
```

**The one I built using Loop; here I only put two webpages**

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
a <- c("https://fortune.com/company/walmart/","https://fortune.com/company/amazon-com/")

find_by_name <- function(list_data, name, elem = NULL) {
  idx <- which(sapply(list_data, \(x) x$name) == name, arr.ind = TRUE)
  stopifnot(length(idx) > 0)
  if (length(idx) > 1) { idx <- idx[1] }
  dat <- list_data[[idx]]
  if (is.null(elem)) dat else dat[[elem]]
}

for (n in 1:length(a)){
  json_data <- list()
  json_data[[n]] <- read_html(a[n]) |>
    html_element("script#preload") |> 
    html_text() |>
    sub("\\s*window\\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ", "", x = _, perl = TRUE) |>
    sub(";\\s*$", "", x = _, perl = TRUE) |>
    fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE)
  
  
  temp<-data[n,"NA"]
  temp[n]<-gsub(".*https://fortune.com","",(a[n]))
  page_data[n] <- json_data[n]$components$page[[temp[n]]]
  
  
  info_data[n] <- page_data[[n]] |> 
    find_by_name("body", "children") |>
    find_by_name("company-about-wrapper", "children") |>
    find_by_name("company-information", "config")
  
  
  info_data[n]$employees
}
```

And here is the error:

> Error in page_data[[n]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Where is `json_data` defined? Because that variable is a different type now in your code block. Also, `json_data$components$page[[temp[n]]]` may need to be changed to `json_data[n]$components$page[[temp[n]]]`, just like you've done with `info_data[n]$employees` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. But I didn't quite get your first point. Could you please elaborate on it? json_data was defined in the second block of the original code and the first block within the loop.

Comment: As far as I can see, `json_data[n]` is assigned to, inside the loop. But the array itself is never defined before that.

Comment: Thanks, 9769953. I may or may not understand your insight and it seems that I am touching on some advanced knowledge of R. So, I should define json_data[n] first, but how....I thought the read_html function's output defines it....

Comment: No, this is quite generic to most programming languages: you define an array first, to be of certain type and length, and then you assign the individual elements. There may be a way around it, but this is how you would do it with your current code.

Comment: You may want to step back and read some R tutorials, especially several sections considering arrays.

Comment: As @9769953 says, define the json_data prior to running the loop like this: `json_data <- list()`, then change the assignment `json_data[n]` to `json_data[[n]]`. This should fix the problem with assigning to the arrray/list.

Comment: @brandbech : Thanks, I learned something new in R. Is this is a standard way to dynamically create/add new elements to an array, or rather something not normally to use?

Comment: @brandbech : Thanks, brandbech. I edited the code as you suggested. However, there is still an error regarding temp[n]. Could you please help take another look?

Comment: @9769953 My apologies. I attributed stuff others were saying to you.